# Why are some programs not getting focused correctly?

Tags: unity, compiz

Why sometimes when I open a picture or Skype (probably there are other programs with the same behavior, but I don't remember now) the Image Viewer / Skype is not focused.

It doesn't happen all the time. I cannot catch the exact condition when this happens, but it really bothers me because often I close the wrong program.

Answer (score 1):

This is related to your focus stealing preventing settings in Compiz.

Install Compizconfig-settings-manager from the software centre, open it, and then go to general options, and in there, set your focus stealing prevention level to a higher level:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

(NOTE: this answer might be Xfce-specific, I have not used gnome or unity enough to know)

In the window manager tweaks setting page, the focus tab allows you to change how focus is shared between programs.